# MULE 3.2 - How to access Flow Session Property Values from a java component

Tags: components, message, esb, mule, transformer-model

This Question relates to Mule ESB 3.2.

If I have read values from JMS, transform to JSON and store the values in my session like this:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="save values to session">            
        <add-message-property key="id" value="#[json-node://id]"/>
        <add-message-property key="name" value="#[json-node://name]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>   

<component class="org.mule.example.echo.Echo"/>
```

How do I access these property values from a java component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your class must implement the `org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable` interface. Then you can get the properties values inside the `onCall` method like this

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
   String id = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("id", PropertyScope.SESSION);
   String name = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("name", PropertyScope.SESSION);
   //Do the rest of your stuff
}
```

Comment: I've found another way to do this with annotations, check [Creating Service Objects and Transformers Using Annotations](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Creating+Service+Objects+and+Transformers+Using+Annotations#Annotations-AnnotationsReference)

Answer (score 1):

If the properties are added with OutboundScope  then the simple

```
public void process(@Payload String payload, @OutboundHeaders Map headers ){
   String id =   headers.get("name") 
}
```

will return you flow property